# EF Query With Conditional Include

Tags: entity-framework

I have two tables: a WorkItem table, and a WorkItemNote table. How do I return a WorkItem and all of the WorkItemNotes that meet a certain criteria?

I think this should be simple, almost like a conditional "Include", right?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I've been planning on writing [a tip](http://blogs.msdn.com/alexj/archive/2009/03/26/index-of-tips.aspx) on this but your question beat me to the punch.

Assuming a `WorkItem` has many `WorkItemNotes`

you can do this:

```
var intermediary = (from item in ctx.WorkItems
              from note in item.Notes
              where note.SomeProp == SomeValue
              select new {item, note}).AsEnumerable();
```

This produces an anonymous element for each `WorkItemNote` that matches, and holds the corresponding `WorkItem` too.

EF identity resolution insures that the same `WorkItem` (by reference) is returned multiple times if it has multiple `WorkItemNotes` that match the criteria.

I assume that next you want to just get back to just the `WorkItems`, like this:

```
var workItems = intermediary.Select(x => x.item).Distinct().ToList();
```

Then if you now do this:

```
foreach(var workItem in workItems)
{
   Console.WriteLine(workItem.Notes.Count)
}
```

You will see that `WorkItemNotes` that match the original filter have been added to the Notes collection of each `workItem`.

This is because of something called Relationship Fixup.

I.e. this gives you what you want conditional include.

Hope this helps

[Alex](http://twitter.com/adjames)

Comment: Really? x.Item will have the appropriate WorkItemNotes? That's awesome! I'm glad you posted this because what I currently have queries the db for every WorkItem. Thanks!

Comment: One question: Why does intermediary have to be IEnumerable? Can it be IQueryable?

Comment: Yeap this works. You can use this for other tricks too, like sorting, see Tip 1 of my tips series!

Comment: It needs to be IEnumerable because otherwise the projecting code changes the query plan, and only the WorkItem is pulled back.

But in this particular case I don't think the PERF would be any better even if you could use IQueryable.

Comment: Alex: I wish I could give you more upvotes; this works like a charm! I also used your tip # 22 to include related objects for WorkItemNote. Thanks again!

Comment: @Alex, I want to extend the statement above to do add a where clause to WorkItems, but the catch is..... I want to include all workItem records even if they dont have a workItemNote.  (when i do it, I only get workitem records that have a note.  I hope you can help me!

Comment: @Alex, Hang on... I worked it out.                                  
WorkItems.Where(q => q.TypeID == 1).Select(q => new {
WorkItem = q,
Note = q.Notes.Where(a => a.Code == "5")
})
Thanks for the starting point.

Comment: @AlexJames What if "SomeValue" was a list of objects from a database? I'm using row level security to give granular CRUD access to each WorkItemNotes.  This uses a join table.  I'm trying Tip8 from your blog, but I can't get it to work. I will also need to include the permissions with each WorkItemNote (probably easiest with an Eager Load via the FK) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8190177/ef-query-with-conditional-include-that-uses-joins

Comment: And over 2 years later, this is still helping people!  Thank you.

Any chance we can get an .Include that implements conditional including natively?

Comment: In EF6 (with db first) this is working for me only if lazy loading is disabled, otherwise it loads everything. Can you help me how to fix this?