# EF Where clause in an Include

Tags: entity-framework-4

from this example that I stole from the net:

```
Company company = context.Companies
                     .Include("Employee.Employee_Car")
                     .Include("Employee.Employee_Country")
                     .FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == companyID);
```

if I want a where clause in the include of Employee_Car for example, how do I do that? Say I just want it to retrieve blue cars.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer is you can't do it just through using the include. You will need to do a bit of joining.
So taking this [tip post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/10/13/tip-37-how-to-do-a-conditional-include.aspx) and the [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1535618/560237) you could do something like along these lines. (Note not exactly your return type but the closest)

```
var companyBlueCars = from company in context.Companies
                      where company.Id == companyID 
                      select new 
                      {
                          company,
                          blueCars = from employee in company.Employees
                                     where employee.Employee_Car.Colour == "blue"
                                     select employee.Employee_Car
                      };
```

(I did make a couple guesses about the data structure but the idea is there.)

Comment: That's cool, I borrowed the example from another question here because it probably makes more sense than my financial modelling one :) Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

You will not do that because include doesn't support filtering or sorting. You must execute two separate queries to load companies and cars with their filters.