# Conditional Include in EF Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

So in my query I have multiple then include to include all the related data. In the last include statement I want to add a condition, but I am getting an "**invalid lambda expression** response because of my linq statements.

```
Class Sample1 
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public ICollection<Sample2> S2 { get; set;}
}
Class Sample2
{
   public Sample3 S3 { get; set; }
   public Sample1 S1 { get; set;}
}
Class Sample3
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public ICollection<Sample4> S4 { get; set;}
}
Class Sample4 
{
   public Sample3 S3 { get; set; }
   public Sample5 S5 { get; set;}
}
Class Sample5
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public bool isPresent { get; set;}
}
```

What I need is when I query **Sample 1**, I want it to include everything till **Sample 3** but only to include **Sample 4 if Sample5.IsPresent** is true.This is the query I am sending

```
var sample = await dbcontext.Sample1.Include(s1 => s1.S2).ThenInclude(s2 => s2.S3)
    .ThenInclude(s3 => s3.S4.Where(s4 => s4.S5.isPresent)).FirstOrDefaultAsync(s => s.Id==id);
```

I have tried using **Any** instead of **Where** but that didn't work either. 
I'd really appreciate any help on this. I have tried doing what some answers on related questions had suggested but none seemed to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Entity Framework Core 3.1**

There is still no option in Entity Framework Core 3.1, here is opened issue:

https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/1833

> This is added to the Backlog in milestone 5.0.0 few days ago.

You should try [Query Include Filter](https://entityframework-plus.net/ef-core-query-filter) or similar extensions. Otherwise you can mix lambda with query expression. See this topic: [EF Query With Conditional Include](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535443/ef-query-with-conditional-include).

**Entity Framework Core 5.0 and above**

Filtered include was introduced in EF Core 5.0.

```
var filteredBlogs = context.Blogs
        .Include(
            blog => blog.Posts
                .Where(post => post.BlogId == 1)
                .OrderByDescending(post => post.Title)
                .Take(5))
        .ToList();
```

More information here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager#filtered-include

Comment: Thanks, that's a real bummer. I wanted to avoid using queryfilter since that will give me way too many methods where I will have to add ignorequeryfilter which I believe gives the wrong picture about its requirement/necessity but I'd rather use that over mixing ef with raw sql.

Comment: You might want to update the answer as 5.0 really brought this feature: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-5.0/whatsnew#filtered-include