# EF: how do I use a include with a where statement?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-6.0, entity-framework-plus

I have an Employee with an Employment and I want to get a list of all employees with a valid employment.

The valid code in SQL would be

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Employees AS employee INNER JOIN
  dbo.Employment AS employment ON employee.ID = employment.Employee_ID AND 
  employment.StartDate <= '2022-3-31' AND (employment.EndDate IS NULL OR
                         employment.EndDate >= '2022-3-31')
```

If I try something like this I C# I would expect to be able to use this

```
var date = DateTime.Now

context.employee.include(x => x.Employment.Where(y => y.Employment.StartDate <= date && ((x.Employment.Enddate ==null) || (x.Employment.Enddate >= date))
```

But this doesn't work.

I have also tried to include Z.EntityFramework.Plus.EFCore and use the following code

```
var date = DateTime.Now

context.employee.includeFilter(x => x.Employment.Where(y => y.Employment.StartDate <= date && ((x.Employment.Enddate ==null) || (x.Employment.Enddate >= date))
```

But this does give me results but will include also the people without an employment

Could somebody give me a hint how to fix this?

Maurice

Comment: try context.employee.includeFilter(x => x.Employment.Where(y => y.Employment.StartDate <= date && ((x.Employment.Enddate == null) || (x.Employment.Enddate >= date)) &&
y.Employee_ID != null))

Comment: Does this answer your question? [EF Query With Conditional Include](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535443/ef-query-with-conditional-include)

Comment: Do you care about employment?

Comment: If I use .EnableSensitiveDataLogging(); I can see the generated SQL code and if I copy/paste this to SQL I get 83 results. Exactly what I expect. But the code of me or Gaurav does give me 308 results.

The following will cleanup the results
var cleanResults = results.Where(x => x.Employment.Count != 0) 
results=308 records big
cleanResults = 83 records big

But I would expect this is done during the original query

Comment: if tables are properly defined relationship in DB then INCLUDE else JOIN works for both. also what is the difference you are seeing in generated SQL vs your query.

Comment: @GauravChaudhary Inside C# the generated code gives me a tolist with 308 results. The SQL code from the sensitiveLogging will give me inside SQL management studio query the expected 83 results.

Comment: See the duplicate, esp. the part that explains that you need to filter both the query and the `Include`.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just do

```
context.Employees.Include(x => x.Employment)
    .Where(x => x.Employments.Any(employment => 
              employment.StartDate <= date &&
              (employment.EndDate == null || employment.EndDate > date)));
```

Given that a person can be employed multiple times in the same company....

Comment: I tried this but EF will make the following code from this resulting in even people with an old contact to popup (so some will have 2 or 3 rows in the results)

SELECT *
FROM [Employees] AS [e]
LEFT JOIN [Employment] AS [e1] ON [e].[ID] = [e1].[Employee_ID]
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM [Employment] AS [e0]
    WHERE ([e].[ID] = [e0].[Employee_ID]) AND (([e0].[StartDate] <= @__date_0) AND (([e0].[EndDate] IS NULL) OR ([e0].[EndDate] >= @__date_1))))

Comment: While the code below does give me the right amount of results

SELECT *
FROM [Employees] AS [e]
LEFT JOIN [Employment] AS [e1] ON [e].[ID] = [e1].[Employee_ID]
    WHERE ([e].[ID] = [e1].[Employee_ID]) AND (([e1].[StartDate] <= @__date_0) AND (([e1].[EndDate] IS NULL) OR ([e1].[EndDate] >= @__date_1)))