# Many to Many select in LINQ to Entities

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, many-to-many

I have two tables `Service` and `Provider`. Between them is a joining table `ServiceProvider` which has only 2 fields - one for each of the two PKs. When added to the edmx the joining many-to-many table is abstracted away and can't be seen (as expected).

This is all fine except when I want to get Providers based on a given service. From this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/793645/entity-framework-linq-to-entities-many-to-many-query-problems):

it looks like the answer would be simply:

```
var query = from p in entities.Providers
            from s in entities.Services
            where s.Id == 15
            select p;
```

but this returns ALL providers. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Does `s` not have a `Providers` property you can use?

Comment: Yes s.Providers is a collection of Providers, but I couldn't get that to work as part of the select either.

Comment: @abatishchev - thanks for edits but won't changing the title make the question harder to find if someone searches for entity framework many-to-many? (I realise its EF defined by the tag, but will a search pick up on that)

Comment: @finoutlook: You're always free to change the title back, my edit is just a suggestion, as to do not put tags in the beginning of a title, but if you want - make it more in a literary style.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var query = entities.Providers.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == 15).Services.ToList();
```

Comment: I think you've got your `Providers` and `Services` the wrong way around.

Comment: Yeah it was providers I was trying to output, but I see its symmetrical anyway

Comment: @finoutlook: The correct solution is in Maciej Dopieralski answer. The code in this answer here will 1) crash when there is no provider with Id=15, 2) crash if you are using POCOs and don't have enabled lazy loading, 3) create two database queries instead of only one. Rawling's answer has the same flaws.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var res = from s in entities.Services
          where s.Id == 15
          select s.Provider;
```

**EDIT**

Corrected and tested the query on real-life model and data. It works now.

Comment: That's not going to work in a many to many relationship, as collection types usually don't have an `Id` property.

Answer (score 2):

Isn't it as simple as

```
var matchingProviders = entities.Services.Single(s=>s.Id==15).Providers;
```

Comment: This works. I'm still confused why the other question I mentioned got upvotes - and this post has the same 'double from' suggestion: http://smehrozalam.wordpress.com/2010/06/29/entity-framework-queries-involving-many-to-many-relationship-tables/

Comment: @finoutlook I'm not very familiar with the entity framework, but if this works - and it doesn't seem too farfetched for it to work - then it works :)

Comment: halit got answer in first, which is very similar (albeit the selecting the wrong side) - but don't know if edits were after your answer

Comment: @fin I wouldn't have assumed this worked and posted my answer if I hadn't seen halit's, so I won't be put out if you accept his :) (Although I prefer my use of `Single` to `FirstOrDefault` too.)

Comment: I'll accept earlier answer, thanks for the help though I'll upvote

Comment: @Rawling: I didn't downvote but reason for the downvote might be that your solution will create *two* database queries and doesn't work at all if lazy loading is not enabled. Maciej Dopieralski's answer solves both problems.

Answer (score -1):

You may try using `join`, like so:

```
entity.Providers.Join(entity.Services, c => c.ID, p => p.ID,(c, p) => new { Providers= c, Services= p })
```

Comment: Why should the provider ID equal the service ID? Why are you selecting a { Providers, Services } pair when fin just wants a list of providers?

Comment: just proposing him a way that he could understand. He can set later and remove what he don't need

Comment: So he could remove the `Join` statement?

Comment: entity framework already know joins. You didn't have to specify here.